# Is there any guarenteed way to mimic some action between `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` methods of an activity being recreated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, mutablelivedata, mutablelist

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259977/mutablelivelist-class-for-android) I have written a `MutableLiveList<T>` class that is intended to replace `MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>` in my project. This is working fine till now. But if multiple modifications are done to the list when that activity is in inactive state, then only the last modification to that list will trigger adapter notify methods. In this case I don't know will the app crash. So I needed to mimic that situation exactly. When the screen rotates, activity gets destroyed and recreated. But I don't know how to add items to that list between that interval. Anyone please help me. Or tell me a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them in the activity's `onDestroy` callback function. At that point the activity's `Lifecycle` object is either in the `CREATED` or `DESTROYED` state:

[image: A chart of how a Lifecycle object's states change with app lifecycle events]

Point is it's not in the `STARTED` state at that point, [and](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata):

> `LiveData` considers an observer, which is represented by the `Observer` class, to be in an active state if its lifecycle is in the `STARTED` or `RESUMED` state. **`LiveData` only notifies active observers about updates.** Inactive observers registered to watch `LiveData` objects aren't notified about changes.

So by the time you're in `onDestroy`, any observer using that activity's `Lifecycle` won't see any updates from the `LiveData`. So you should be able to add values to the `LiveData` without getting notified.

---

By the way, that "only notified of the last value" update [is by design](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects):

> Generally, `LiveData` delivers updates only when data changes, and **only to active observers**. An exception to this behavior is that **observers also receive an update when they change from an inactive to an active state**. Furthermore, if the observer changes from inactive to active a second time, it only receives an update if the value has changed since the last time it became active.

So if the data goes `A, B, C` while the observer is inactive, it won't be notified of those values. When it goes from inactive to inactive, it'll get the most recent value, `C`. It doesn't save a history of all the values an observer has missed

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I got confused and thought activity will get destroyed after the call to `onDestry()`. Code written in `onDestroy()` worked as expected. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well it will get destroyed *after* that function, but not while it's running the code in there ;)

Comment: It comes to `DESTROYED` state before call to `onDestroy()`. True or False? :|

Comment: I don't know for sure, that's why I said it's either ``CREATED`` or ``DESTROYED`` at that point. From the diagram it looks like it moves to ``DESTROYED`` **after** the ``onDestroy`` call chain finishes. That's just the state of the ``Lifecycle`` object though, not the activity itself. The ``Lifecycle`` object is what lets the ``LiveData`` decide whether an observer is active or not when it wants to push a value